# How to setup a vpn between my pc and my server 2012

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to setup a vpn connection between my PC and my home-network and have access to the local resources that I can use when i'm at a remote location like a hotel.

I have a windows server 2012 r2 and couple of PCs running windows 8.1 and a Netgear router R6250

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Install a VPN server on your Windows server and address specific problems that you face.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server has a VPN server built into it.  All you have to do is install the server role and follow the Wizard.

Here is a [write up](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/07/how-to-install-vpn-on-windows-server-2012/).

Comment: So i fallowed the directions and connected successfully, but I am unable to browse my internal network or access the internet.